# Coupon collecting with unequal probabilities (S.Ross Min-Max approach)

Tags: probability, coupon-collector

While going through a method to solve the coupon collecting problem , the author posed the problem as follows :

Suppose there are $n$ types of coupons and that each time one collects a coupon, it is, independently of previous coupons collected, a type $i$ coupon with probability $~~p_i~$,$~~\sum_{i=1}^n p_{i}=1$  .

Find the expected number of coupons one needs to collect to obtain a

complete set of at least one of each type.

Then in his attempt to the solution he defined his random variables the following way :

let $X_{i}$ denote the number of coupons one needs to collect to obtain a type $i$ coupon , and let  $X$ be the number of coupons one needs to collect to obtain 
a complete set of at least one of each type.

After that he made this proposition :   $~~~~X= \underset{i=1,...n}{{max}} {X_{i}}$ .

Question : Why is this formula true ? To me this relation doesn't sound obvious at all ,  could someone help me  clarify that  please ?

Source : A first Course In Probability (S.Ross ) p320.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X_i$ is not, as the other answer states, the expected number of draws to obtain coupon $i$. It is the number of draws to obtain coupon $i$. It is a random variable, not the expected value of that random variable. Likewise, $X$ is a random variable, namely the number of draws required to obtain at least one coupon of each type; it is not the expected value of that number. The equation

$$
X= \underset{i=1,\ldots,n}\max {X_{i}}
$$

is true for the random variables but not for their expected values. For the random variables, it is true simply because you've collected each coupon type at least once precisely at the time at which you've collected the last coupon type at least once.

Comment: Ah, thank you for pointing out that part. Will edit my answer

Comment: @joriki it really became clearer but one last thing : $\max(X_{i})$ represents the number of trials needed to obtain the type $i$ coupon only $1$ time , but $X$ could include the possibility of including more than one type $i$ coupon isn't it ? Unless $X_{i}$ represents the number of trials needed to obtain type $i$ coupon at least once not exactly once .

Comment: @Hilbert If you like, $X_i$ is the number of the draw on which you draw coupon $i$ for the first time.

Comment: @Hilbert: There's no difference between "the number of trials needed to obtain type $i$ at least once" and "the number of trials needed to obtain type $i$ exactly once". At the first time at which you have at least one coupon of type $i$ for the first time, you necessarily have exactly one, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the point being made is this:

Remember $X_i$ is the number of draws until coupon $i$ is finally picked. Therefore, $\text{max}(X_i)$ represents the most draws needed to obtain a certain coupon. In theory if you finally obtain this "rare" coupon, you should have drawn at least one of all the others.

However, note that the expected value of $X$ is not equal to $\text{max}(X_i)$

Comment: Does the proof of the proposition just stated requires some advanced mathematics  or it can be proved using introductory probability ?

Comment: It may require more than the basics to prove it. Personally I have some issues with this argument, but I can see the point being made here. The issue I have is this: suppose instead of coupons, we are rolling a dice until we roll each side at least once. By this argument, you would expect the answer to be $6$ rolls on average, but it's actually closer to $14$ (proofs of this can be found if you search a little). But if we have one $p_i$ that is much much smaller than the rest of them, then $max(X_i)$ should be much closer to the true expected value.